# Is it possible to programmatically generate an Excel file containing an Org Chart?

Tags: c#, excel, orgchart

I have a set of data that represents a company hierarchy. I would like to export this to Excel and have it display an Org Chart (essentially a graphical representation of the hierarchy). The manual steps for creating this type of chart in Excel are outlined here: https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/how-to-make-an-org-chart-in-excel but I was hoping there may be some way to generate the file so there is no manual intervention required to generate the chart. Is this possible, or will there always need to be manual configuration?

I have researched online but been unable to find any reference to this particular issue. Whilst I am familiar with exporting data into various formats, I am not familiar with exporting to Excel chart formats.

I intend to write the solution in C# but any experience of resolving the above issue in any programming language would be very useful and much appreciated.

Comment: What library are you using to create the Excel file?

Comment: @gunr2171 Historically I've used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: This is the first link for the google search "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel smartart": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addsmartart?view=excel-pia

Comment: Ok, thanks - I’ll have a play with that and see if I can’t figure out how to get what I need. Thanks @gunr2171